# Retrofit + Basic Authentication

Tags: android, retrofit2, basic-authentication

I've implemented retrofit with basic authentication, I send the @header on my login request but when i call some authenticated request it returns me 401 (Not authorizated).

How I implement it generic? Or i always need to call my authenticated requests with @header?

```
@GET("user")
Call<User> getUserByEmail(@Query("email") String email, @Header("Authorization") String authorization);
```

When i call Get User By Email (I authenticate the user)...

```
@PUT("usuario/{userId}/")
Call<User> putUserById(@Path("userId") Integer id, @Body User user);
```

When i call Put user ( i need to make an authenticated request).

My retrofit class...

```
public class NetworkService {
private NetworkAPI networkAPI;
private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

public NetworkService() {
    okHttpClient = buildClient();
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BuildConfig.HOST)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build();

    networkAPI = retrofit.create(NetworkAPI.class);
}

public NetworkAPI getAPI() {
    return networkAPI;
}

private OkHttpClient buildClient() {

    OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

    builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Response response = chain.proceed(chain.request());

            return response;
        }
    });

    builder.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            //this is where we will add whatever we want to our request headers.
            Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();
            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    return builder.build();
}
}
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: *Or i always need to call my authenticated requests with @header?* that depends on how you implemented auth on your server and how you identify requests/devices

Comment: Can you show me an example to make it generic?

Comment: You can add headers in request of RequestInterceptor and add that interceptor to your RestAdapter. And for every request use this rest adapter,So that you need not to add header every time.

Comment: I cannot show you an example. Did you even read what I said?

Comment: Oh, now i understand... I'm using spring-boot to make my server-side. Using WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter to block requests...

Answer (score 2):

use @Header("Authorization") String authorization in NetworkService

```
 Request request = chain.request().newBuilder()
                    .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .addHeader("Authorization", "AuthorizationValue")
                    .build();
```

Comment: you can simple checking if(islogin){.addHeader("Authorization", "AuthorizationValue")}

Comment: I need to save the information on my Application class?

Comment: you can use shared preference for save and load

Comment: What is **chain.request**?

Answer (score 0):

If you use Retrofit 2 and here is a sample for some basic authentication in headers

```
public interface SomeApi {
@Headers({
   "Content-Type: application/json",
   "Authorization: Basic KzY1OTY0MjA4NTQ6MTExMTE="
})
@POST("test/someService")
Completable getTrips();
```

}

Comment: What if I need to provide dynamic authorization headers?

Comment: Static authorization tokens is _not_ an approach that should be used

Answer (score 0):

```
  Step 1:
public interface ApiConnection {
     @GET("GET_LOCAL/{id}")
        fun colony(@Header("Authorization") authkey:String? ,
                      @Path("id") id:String?): Call<JsonObject> }

 step 2: create static Gloabalmethod 
fun Authpass(): String {
                    var data = ByteArray(0)
                    try {data =(CommonStatic.commonVariable.API_USERNAME + ":" + CommonStatic.commonVariable.API_PASSWORD).toByteArray(
                                charset("UTF-8"))
                    } catch (e: UnsupportedEncodingException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
               return "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP)
                }
 Step 3:Retrofit Class
fun getSTP(): ApiCon? {
        val gson: Gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()
        val r: Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(CommonStatic.commonVariable.BASE_URL_PTS)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build()
        return r.create(ApiConnection::class.java)
    }
step 4 : call 


try {
 val call: Call<JsonObject>?=RetrofitCall.retrofit.getSTP()?.colony(GloabalClass.GloabalMethod.Authpass(),id)
 if (call != null) {
       call.enqueue(object : Callback<JsonObject> {
     override fun onResponse(call: Call<JsonObject>, response: Response<JsonObject>) 
 {
       if (response.isSuccessful) {
        val ward : JsonObject? = response.body()
        val jsonObject = JSONObject(ward.toString())
     val colonyArray: JSONArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Result")} else {Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()}}override fun onFailure(call: Call<JsonObject>, t: Throwable) {
  Log.d("loginAuthendication", "failure--" + t.toString())
 Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "NO INTERNET CONNECTION ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                            }
                        }) }
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.d("loginAuthendication", e.toString())
            }
```